# How to use predefined database in Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: sql, windows-phone-7

I have been learning Windows Phone 7 for quite some time now. However with the new mango update we can use sql db on WP7.1. My problem is, I have my db ready populated with tables and data, so how can i use it in my application? Like how to deploy it to the isolated storage during installation and before that how to try it on emulator???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Local Database Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), section Application Deployment